# How to send media WhatsApp message using Twilio without sandbox?

Tags: image, twilio, media, sandbox, send

We have registered a template in some format.so if we have a sent a text with same format message is getting delivered but if we have any image it is not getting delivered.

```
    String from = "";
    String to = "";
    //String to = "";
    String imgUrl = "https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png";

    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Message message = Message.creator(
                    new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:"+to),
                    new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:"+from),
                    "Here's that picture of an owl you requested.")
            .setMediaUrl(
                    Arrays.asList(URI.create(imgUrl)))
            .create();`
```

Comment: What is the result of the code above? Do you receive a message without the image or no message at all?